# In Amazon Lex, How to get the post message from Facebook

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am using following code to post message back to Amazone Lex

```
....


    var objItem = {
                "title": `(£${item.price} pw) ${item.street_name}`,
                "image_url": item.image_url,
                "subtitle": `${item.displayable_address}`,
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": `${item.details_url}`,
                        "title": "View"
                    }, {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "Book Item",
                        "payload": {vid:"CAL00002"}
                    }
                ]
            }

....
```

When the button ***"Book Item"***,is clicked,currently, the message  "payload": {vid:"CAL00002"} will be sent back to Amazon Lex.  it seems that Amazon Lex don't know this message, so I can NOT get this object in Amazon Lambda functions. here I am using Amazon Lex as AI to learn user's intent, and then all business logic is implemented in Amazon Lambda.  in this situation, how can I post message back to Lambda? or Is there a way to post structured message back to Lex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are sending message back to Lambda, but I'm using [AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html#postText-property) to do this. Whatever information I want Lambda to get, I put it in `sessionAttributes` to pass.